# Is there any way to find the values of one cell based on the value of other cell in Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I have get an value of a cell in excel spread sheet based on the value of other cell. I have an XLSX in which one columns contains the city names and the other contain the state for that names. So, what I want to do is like find "Orange City" where state is "CA". From what I know I'll have to iterate over each row and each column to find the city and then iterate two columns ahead (as the state is after two columns) to check if the state code is correct.

Is there any other efficient way to do this? (It would have been so easy in databases..)

Comment: Use a database? (Most likely by using Apache POI to grab the data out of the spreadsheet)

Comment: Can't really use a database.